# Text on a single line instead of wrap

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I don't understand why my text is on a single line instead of wrapping inside the container.

[image: Example]

My theme is based on foundation 5 and I didn't write any css line for my texts. That's the code I wrote now:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog Page
*/

get_header();
?>

<?php
$args = array('post_per_page' => 10);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-blog-sidebar' ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
        <?php
         foreach($posts as $post):
             setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
             <article post-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <hr />
                 <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
             </article>
         <?php

         endforeach;
         wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'right-blog-sidebar' ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php
        get_footer();
    ?>
</div>
```

link to page: tinyurl.com/ttttt6577

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: CSS width value somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is wrong but I have copied your content in notepad file once. Then I have copied the same from notepad file and added the same in your site using developer console and it works fine, Text is wrapped correctly then after.

I would suggest to do the same with your database content as well.

[image]

Comment: The problem may be that content are grabbed from db?

Comment: @vuudd00 when I have checked your content in console, it was showing `&nbsp;` between two words. But when I have added content from notepad, it was not there. That is the only difference I have found in my result. I would suggest to copy content in notepad once and add content from notepad to your WordPress editor. I hope you are using text editor instead of Visual.?

Comment: Nope because the final user will use the visual one so it has to work with both of them.

Comment: @vuudd00 Yes I agree , it should work with both. But just come the solution I wanted to understand the real problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must consider this idea.

1.) Be sure that the parent element has a width lesser than the window screen width.
2.) Be sure that the text you have added in not continous, I mean the words are separated with space.

Comment: it has % width im using foundation grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`text-wrap: normal;` or
`white-space: normal;` or
`word-break: break-all;`

on the parent div or inner paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code to your themes css file.

```
   article p {
       word-break: break-all !important;
   }
```

Comment: i didn't want to use any of these rules becuase it must do it by default. the div has a % width cause im using the foundation grid system.

Comment: You better provide the link of the website page.

Comment: is at bottom of my post. auth credentials are admin paolo021@

Comment: Ok, But the page is redirecting to http://dev.superyeah.it/ and asking for the username and password.

Comment: credentials are admin , paolo021@